# Dynamic SelectList not selecting specified value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.Net MVC6 and Entity Framework 7

I am populating select boxes on a edit form using a database table and attempting to select proper record. For some reason the selected variable isn't getting pushed at all and the first record is always selected regardless of what the database reflects.

Here is the form helper

```
<select asp-for="SeasonId" asp-items="Model.SeasonList" class="form-control"></select>
```

Here is the controller

```
var match = _context.Matches.Single(m => m.MatchId == id);
SeasonList = new SelectList(_context.Seasons, "SeasonId", "SeasonName", match.SeasonId)
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
public int SeasonId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SeasonList { get; set; }
public Season Season { get; set; }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `SeasonId` value of your view model to the option value you want to be selected.

```
var vm=new YourViewModel();
var match = _context.Matches.Single(m => m.MatchId == id);
vm.SeasonList = _context.Seasons
                 .Select(x=>new SelectListItem { Value= x.SeasonId.ToString(),
                                                 Text= x.SeasonName).ToList();
vm.SeasonId= match.SeasonId;
return View(vm);
```